# Angular 2 - Why imported module routing order is different to fix-coded?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Let's say i'have this in my app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     HttpModule,
     RouterModule.forRoot([
        {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
        {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
        {path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent},
     ]),
     UserModule
     ...
})
```

this leads in my opinion to this routing order:

> {path: 'User', component: UserComponent}, 
>  
>   {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
>   {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
>   {path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent}

*Note that User is now before the others.*

Now i am exporting the part *RouterModule.ForRoot* to another module called *AppRoutingModule*.

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     HttpModule,
     AppRoutingModule, // newly created routing module
     UserModule
     ...
})
```

this leads now to this in my opinion:

> {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
>   {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
>   {path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent}, 
>  
>   {path: 'User', component: UserComponent}

*Note that User is now after the others.*

So i have to put the AppRoutingModule below the UserModule. Why is it implemented like this?

Comment: Where and how is that User route defined?

Answer (score 2):

Here are two links from the official documentation that will help you understand how imports are made, and how to know the current order route :

- https://angular.io/guide/router#inspect-config

**App.Module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent },
  { path: 'hero/:id',      component: HeroDetailComponent },
  {
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroListComponent,
    data: { title: 'Heroes List' }
  },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/heroes',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
    // other imports here
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> The order of the routes in the configuration matters and this is by
>   design. The router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching
>   routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific
>   routes. In the configuration above, routes with a static path are
>   listed first, followed by an empty path route, that matches the
>   default route. The wildcard route comes last because it matches every
>   URL and should be selected only if no other routes are matched first.

**App.Module.ts**

```
// Diagnostic only: inspect router configuration
constructor(router: Router) {
  console.log('Routes: ', JSON.stringify(router.config, undefined, 2));
}
```

- https://angular.io/guide/router#module-import-order-matters